# The file cannot be validated as the host "struts.apache.org" is currently unreachable

Tags: java, model-view-controller, struts-1

In struts-config.xml under declaration of Doc type

```
<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC
      "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.3//EN"
      "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-config_1_3.dtd">
```

at url "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-config_1_3.dtd" in the xml getting below message as  ***"The file cannot be validated as the host "struts.apache.org" is currently unreachable."***

Due to this iam unable to deploy the application.

anyidea how to resolve the above issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link in your question works fine for me, but the link below is what I'm using currently, try it and see?

```
http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/dtds/struts-config_1_3.dtd
```

Edit: reference dtd locally. I think this should do the trick.

1. copy struts-config_1_3.dtd and then place into /WEB-INF/dtd folder
2. modify the doctype in struts-config.xml to this

   `<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.3//EN" "../dtd/struts-config_1_3.dtd">`

Comment: Would be nice to be able to deploy without making an external network connection, though. There must be an option for that.

Comment: Interesting question, updated the answer on how to reference the dtd locally. I have not tested it yet as I'm away, but I think that should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your lib jar to *struts2-core-2.3.20.jar* so you can use `org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter` in web.xml and accordingly other dependent jars like xwork, ognl, free marker etc.

Despite of warning of structs.xml, application will run now.

Comment: @Aleksandar  I had to mentioned my solution is for struts2. As I face the same warning message when I use org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.